# How can I sort a table in Datastudio by multiple columns?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a report in Datastudio that consists of multiple columns. I'd like to sort the rows based on multiple columns. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The sorting is limited by 2 columns. In the Table Properties-Data pane pick "Sort" and "Secondary Sort" options for primary and secondary sorting.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by [Elena](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555686/12892553), [Tables](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) allow editors to set a default *(Primary) Sort* and an optional *Secondary Sort*.

In addition, while in *View Mode*, users can also sort the Table as required, by either tapping on the respective field header, or by accessing the *Sort Drop-down* in the *Chart Header*.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/681ac76c-fd4d-4b2c-af0c-22e5c3b952d2) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have stated, it looks like Data Studio only supports two sort fields.

You can create a calculated field on the secondary sort, which concatenates together the 2nd and subsequent fields on which to sort by, to approximate sorting on more than two dimensions.